# How to set ipv6 address as siteurl?

Tags: site-url, home-url, ip

I have try to set ipv6 ip address as home and site url, but it seems not work perfectly.

From there: `http://[2001:da8:d800:71::250]/wordpress/`  (if you view the source) we see that some url, such as `pingback` (line 16) where correct, but others, such as `rss` (line 20) were lost `[` and `]`, how to fix this? (if I don't have an domain which point to this ipv6 address.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem here is the [esc_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) function which is used to sanitize a lot of the URLs used in wp-core.

If you have a look at the function definition in [formatting.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2622) you'll see that the regex in line 2627 is filtering out `[` and `]`.

But fortunately you can also see that in line 2656 there is a filter supplied which allows you to overwrite this behavior. So you'll be able to fix this through attaching a custom function to the `clean_url` filter.

---

** ***EDIT2*** **

It seems like redirect URLs are sanitized in another function. Fortunately this is a [pluggable function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), so we are able to overwrite it. I edited the code to take this into account. You can use the following code snippet through creating a `mu-plugins` folder inside your `wp-content` folder and placing a PHP file (I named mine `fix_ipv6_siteurl.php`) inside that folder.

```
<?php

add_filter('clean_url', 'wpse_120978_custom_esc_url', 10, 3);

function wpse_120978_custom_esc_url( $url, $original_url, $_context ) {

    if( !strpos($original_url, '[') ) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = $original_url;

    if ( '' == $url )
            return $url;
    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-[]~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);
    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $url = _deep_replace($strip, $url);
    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);
    /* If the URL doesn't appear to contain a scheme, we
        * presume it needs http:// appended (unless a relative
        * link starting with / or a php file).
        */
    if ( strpos($url, ':') === false &&
            substr( $url, 0, 1 ) != '/' && substr( $url, 0, 1 ) != '#' && !preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+?\.php/i', $url) )
            $url = 'http://' . $url;

    // Replace ampersands and single quotes only when displaying.
    if ( 'display' == $_context ) {
            $url = wp_kses_normalize_entities( $url );
            $url = str_replace( '&amp;', '&#038;', $url );
            $url = str_replace( "'", '&#039;', $url );
    }

    if ( !is_array($protocols) )
            $protocols = array ('http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'svn');
    if ( wp_kses_bad_protocol( $url, $protocols ) != $url )
            return '';

    return $url;
}


if ( !function_exists('wp_sanitize_redirect') ) :
/**
 * Sanitizes a URL for use in a redirect.
 *
 * @since 2.3
 *
 * @return string redirect-sanitized URL
 **/
function wp_sanitize_redirect($location) {
    $location = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-[]~+_.?#=&;,/:%!]|i', '', $location);
    $location = wp_kses_no_null($location);

    // remove %0d and %0a from location
    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $location = _deep_replace($strip, $location);
    return $location;
}
endif;
```

(The previous code from the functions.php can be removed.)

Comment: yep, I believe this in the right direction, but could your give me more code? how the filter in my case?

Comment: @vanabel I edited my answer with some code.

Comment: done! I think you have just remove the `[` and `]` from been filtered out by change the regular expression in `preg_replace`, is it?

Comment: By the way, why you use `wpse_120978_custom_esc_url` as your function? such a long name in my mind.

Comment: Exactly, the regex was just modified to allow `[]` by adding them to the list of allowed chars. You can name the function how you like. I just chose: 120978 = your question id, wpse = wordpress stack exchange and the name of the original function + custom to give it some meaning.

Comment: I think there maybe some other issues about the redirect. As you can see from my site: `http://[2001:da8:d800:71::250]/wordpress/wp-login.php` Just try to login as `tester` and passwd is `123456`, you can see after you click the login (登陆 in my language), you will not redirected to admin page, but you can see from the homepage that you were already logged in. The same problem (can't redirect) appears in switch the theme.

Comment: Too bad. I can't access the site. No ipv6 support from my current ISP. I'll try the same setup on my localhost ...

Comment: @vanabel I think I have found the solution for the redirect problem. I've edited my answer again with the details.

Comment: That's really great, many thanks. It works perfect now!